# Trying to get my head around OOP and wondering if my functions are done correctly

Tags: c++, oop, console-application

I am making a simple little calculator application and I am wondering how best I can incorporate encapsulation and abstraction into my code to make it neat and organised.

Is this an ideal way on how to approach these methods with the following code? I am not sure if it is going a bit overboard but in my eyes it makes it very readable and tidy.

Also is there a rule in saying that if you are repeating code, it belongs in a function?

Thank you in advance.

```
// Test ApplicationV2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>




int getNumber();
char getOperation();
int additionResult(int& val1, int& val2);
int multiplyResult(int& val1, int& val2);
int divisionResult(int& val1, int& val2);

int main()
{
    int val1, val2;
    char operation;

    std::cout << "Enter the first value.";
    val1 = getNumber();

    std::cout << "Enter operation";
    operation = getOperation();

    std::cout << "Enter second number.";
    val2 = getNumber();

    switch (operation)
    {
    case '+':
        std::cout << additionResult(val1, val2);
        break;

    case '*':
        std::cout << multiplyResult(val1, val2);
        break;

    case '/':
        std::cout << divisionResult(val1, val2);
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Please enter sufficient data.";
    }

    //Keep window open
    std::string barn;
    std::cin >> barn;

    return 0;
}

int getNumber()
{
    int x;

    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

char getOperation()
{
    char op;

    std::cin >> op;
    return op;
}

int additionResult(int& val1, int& val2)
{
    return (val1 + val2);
}

int multiplyResult(int& val1, int& val2)
{
    return (val1 * val2);
}

int divisionResult(int& val1, int& val2)
{
    return (val1 / val2);
}
```

Comment: No rule says "if you are repeating code, it belongs in a function".  But good programming technique includes rarely/minimally repeating code.  Moving code to a function is one way to avoid repeating code.  It is not always the best way.

Comment: Also, there is no `OOP` in your code.  It is strictly procedural.

Comment: You could simplify the function names: getNextInput(), add(),multiply(),divide((

Comment: The rule/principle is called [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Your functions should either pass by value, or const reference, if they don't modify the arguments. (In this case, pass by value would be better)

Comment: 'Correctly' => it works. What you're really asking about is good programming style, which certainly exists and even has some objective attributes, but don't confuse it with correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As presented, your program doesn't use OOP (except in as much as `std::cout` and `std::cin` are objects).  If you're aim is to explore using OOP as a way to structure the code, then consider:

```
#include <iostream>

class Calculation
{
  public:
    Calculation(int first, int second)
      : first_(first), second_(second)
    { }

    int add() { return first_ + second_; }
    int multiply() { return first_ * second_; }
    int divide() { return first_ / second_; }

  private:
    int first_, second_;
};

int main()
{
    int val1, val2;
    char operation;

    if (std::cout << "Enter the first value: " &&
        std::cin >> val1 &&
        std::cout << "Enter operation: " &&
        std::cin >> operation &&
        std::cout << "Enter the second value: " &&
        std::cin >> val2)
    {
        Calculation calc(val1, val2);

        switch (operation)
        {
          case '+':
            std::cout << calc.add() << '\n';
            break;

          case '*':
            std::cout << calc.multiply() << '\n';
            break;

          case '/':
            std::cout << calc.divide() << '\n';
            break;

          default:
            std::cerr << "Invalid operator: must be +, * or /.\n";
        }
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Error getting inputs.\n";

    //Keep window open
    std::cin.get();  // real operating systems don't need this ;-P
}
```

Note that the `Calculation` class is the OOP aspect, and it has `private` data: that's encapsulation.  It doesn't abstract much though - problem's too simple - but you could say it's captured the inputs at construction and the `add()`, `multiply()`, `divide()` calls don't have to be aware of the type or quantity of data involved (i.e. `Calculator` might have stored a `std::vector<int>` or a `double` and the `switch` statement's code need not change, provided there's an `operator<<` overload for the return type of those three functions).

You could get a bit more abstraction by having a member function in `Calculation` like:

```
int do_operation(char c) const
{
    switch (c)
    {
      case '+': return first_ + second_;
      case '*': return first_ * second_;
      case '/': return first_ / second_;
      default: throw std::runtime_error("invalid operator character");
    }
}
```

Then the use from `main` can just try an operation and see if it's supported, without knowing the exact operations provided by `Calculation`:

```
Calculation calc(val1, val2);

try
{
    std::cout << calc.do_operation(operation) << '\n';
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "oops - caught exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

This might not seem a big deal, but it means if you've got lots of places using the `Calculation` objects, you don't have to update them all when you want to support another operation.  A disadvantage is that the return type of `do_operation` has to be the same for all the types of operation, so you can't decide *"hey, I'll have divide return a `double` instead of rounding down to an `int`"* and simply change `divide()`'s return type alone (but you could have them all return `double` - won't do much harm in this simple case, and more generally you can use "variant"s to return any of a set of types, but they're harder for the client code to use).

> Also is there a rule in saying that if you are repeating code, it belongs in a function?

Pretty much.  Do note that you weren't repeating (calling twice) any of the code you put into functions, but it gets important in more complex programs.

As an example of factoring the above code using a function, consider how the prompting and input could be combined in a reusable function:

```
template <typename T>
bool input(const std::string& prompt, T& value)
{
    return std::cout << prompt && std::cin >> value;
}
```

The `template <typename T>` thing means the above function can work with any type of `value`.  Using this `input` function, the prompting and input operations can be rewritten as:

```
if (input("Enter the first value: ", val1) &&
    input("Enter operation: ", operation) &&
    input("Enter the second value: ", val2))
{
```

Whether that's better depends on whether the reader can guess at what `input` does well enough not to need to go study the `input` function, but the more often it gets reused the more likely even such an effort would be worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for this very informative comment. I still need to learn about classes so I can refer back to this and it'll make the job a lot easier. 


Thanks!

Comment: @RyanSwann: sounds like a plan.  Classes are the basis of OOP, so unavoidable if you want to learn OOP.  They're often great for code organisation.  Good luck!  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to have an abstract "binary operation" class, and then have derived classes for each of your actual operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division).

If you do this, you can then (for one example) create a container of (pointers or references to) binary operation objects, and look up the correct operation in that collection. For example:

```
struct bin_op { 
    virtual int operator()(int a, int b);
};

struct add : bin_op { 
    virtual int operator()(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};

struct sub : bin_op {
    virtual int operator()(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
};

// mul and div similarly.

std::map<char, bin_op *> ops;

add a;
sub s;
mul m;
div d;

ops['+'] = &a;
ops['-'] = &s;
ops['*'] = &m;
ops['/'] = &d;
```

Then to carry out an operation, you do something like this:

```
auto b = ops.find(operation);

if (b != ops.end())
    std::cout << b->second(val1, val2);
else
    std::cerr << "unknown operation: " << operation << "\n";
```

One obvious advantage of this is that it makes it fairly simple to add new operations: define a new class derived from `bin_op` to carry out your new operation, add an instance of that to `ops` (with the character you want to trigger that operation), and off you go.